# Where to find php_imagick.dll for php 5.5.12 for Windows wampserver 2.5?

Tags: php, dll, wamp, imagick, php-5.5

I am using **Wampserver 2.5 on my Windows 7 (32 bit) and my PHP version is 5.5.12**. I am unable to use **IMAGICK**.

I have installed **IMAGICK version 6.8.9** on my system and it works like charm on the command line.

Further, I have followed instructions to enable it on my wampserver.

1. Inserted "**SetEnv MAGICK_HOME C:/imagemagick**" in httpd.conf at Appache.
2. Downloaded **php_imagick-3.1.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip**
3. Copied and pasted the **php_imagick.dll** from zip to php.ini at Appache.

While running a simple script on php [$a = new Imagick()] **I get the error [Class 'Imagick' not found]**.

Kindly direct me to the right way of installation and the right downloads to **install IMAGICK on Wampserver 2.5 / Windows 7 / 32bit / PHP 5.5.12**.

Answer (score 20):

#### Manual installation of imagick on Wamp, Xampp, and IIS

1. Create a folder imagick in php/ext folder.
2. Now add this newly created php/ext/imagick folder to windows path.
3. Download the latest version of imagick for windows from this link. http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/
4. Download php extension of imagick from this link.
   http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/
5. Before downloading these 2 zip files, match the file name of your installation with your php. 
   for eg. php_imagick-3.2.0b2-5.5-nts-vc11-x86.zip
   -Here 5.5 is the version of php
   -nts is for IIS and windows (wamp) and ts is for Apache and Linux (xampp)
   -VC11 and VC9 are the version of compilation, run phpinfo and check that it match with your php version.
   -x86 is for 32 bit x64 is for 64 bit machines, i recommend use x86 only
6. Once you have downloaded the correct version for your php, extract the downloaded file to imagick folder you have added to path, take all files from bin folder to the root of imagick and replace all
7. Add full path to php_imagick.dll in php.ini like extension=C:\wamp\php\ext\imagick\php_imagick.dll
8. Restart your computer for path to take effect. Then open command and type dcraw and press enter. if you have added the path correctly a list of parameters will be shown, your Imagick is installed sucessfully.
9. Run phpinfo again and you will see Imagick listed as extension.

Comment: The php_imagick.dll is in point no. 3. Follow point 5 to get the correct version.

Comment: The above method thankfully worked. The actual path in step 7 is more complex for the wamp 2.5 install. extension=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\imagick\php_imagick.dll

Comment: The above worked for me, along with the last step from this write-up: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php#92529

Answer (score 0):

I would add a small, but crucial advice, becaues it took me 10 hours of sunday, to get it working.

This is for Win7/10 x64 and Wamp 2.5 x64

There is a php.ini file in apache/bin folder and there should be added a new line with php_imagick.dll extension :)