# ImageMagick supported formats no value in wamp server 2.5

Tags: php, imagick

I try to install imagick on WAMP server but not install.
I follow complete process according to
http://www.jarrodtoh.com/getting-imagick-work-wamp-2-5-php-5-5-12/ 
[Where to find php_imagick.dll for php 5.5.12 for Windows wampserver 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766737/where-to-find-php-imagick-dll-for-php-5-5-12-for-windows-wampserver-2-5/)
I also set `MAGICK_HOME` as environment variable and path `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\imagick\`
Also set `extension=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\imagick\php_imagick.dll` in php.ini file
But in `phpinfo()` `ImageMagick supported formats` display `no value`.

Wamp Server:- 2.5
Window 7 32-Bit Os

I installed `php_imagick-3.1.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip` from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.1.2/
also installed `ImageMagick-6.8.9-1-vc11-x86.zip` from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\imagick` folder.

Comment: This usually happens when Imagick was compiled against a different version of ImageMagick than the one you're installing it with.

Comment: so what i do for that how i solve? are u said to reinstall Imagick or WAMP?

Comment: You should download everything from the same place, if you can.

Comment: Still having this issue even after I copied the files with wamp runing on windows10

Answer (score 0):

Copy all dll files from `path-to-ImageMagick\modules\coders` to `path-to-ImageMagick`. Then restart Apache and run again `phpinfo()`. Supported formats should appear now.

Comment: Still having this issue even after I copied the files with wamp runing on windows10