# ImageMagick not working

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have tried using steps for installing ImageMagick from [How to install ImageMagick for WAMP 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336327/how-to-install-imagemagick-for-wamp-2-5) and from [Where to find php_imagick.dll for php 5.5.12 for Windows wampserver 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766737/where-to-find-php-imagick-dll-for-php-5-5-12-for-windows-wampserver-2-5).
I am using Windows 10 and WAMP 2.5 with PHP 5.5.12. I install using ImageMagick-7.0.3-3-Q16-x64-dll.exe and have tried using a few of this

- php_imagick-3.1.2-5.5-nts-vc11-x64
- php_imagick-3.1.2-5.5-nts-vc11-x64
- php_imagick-3.2.0b1-5.5-nts-vc11-x64
- php_imagick-3.4.3rc1-7.0-nts-vc14-x64

All of them still get me Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 19 from testing if imagemagick is working using these codes

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick();
$im->newPseudoImage(100, 100, "magick:rose");
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->roundCorners(5,3);
$type=$im->getFormat();
header("Content-type: $type");
echo $im->getimageblob();
?>
```

I have put the CORE_RL files into C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
and php_imagick.dll to here: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\
please help!

Comment: have you checked `imagick` in `phpinfo()` is enabled?

Comment: Hi wat do you mean by that? where can i find `phpinfo() `?
In php.ini I have included extension=php_imagick.dll

Comment: please have a look at [phpinfo — Outputs information about PHP's configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Comment: I have run `phpinfo()` but I can't find anything related to imagick. only on some part of the Path there is  C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16

Comment: have you followed instruction given below http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows like: `If you have any problems, you likely need vcomp120.dll. To install it, download [Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)`.

Comment: yes I have already done that. It's still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with ImageMagick working on my Wamp Server for a few hours and have finally figured out how to get it working on my Windows 10 system.

1)  Making sure you have the latest Wamp Server on your system.
2)  Download the latest Windows version of ImageMagick from the ImageMagick server http://www.imagemagick.org
3)  Install it and make sure to use the c:\Imagemagick for installation.
4)  Download the latest Pecl files from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/ select the newest version.
5)  Copy the CORE dll files from that download and put them in the Wamp Server Apache Bin directory.
6)  Copy the php_imagick.dll file from that download and put it into the Wamp Server php ext directory.
7)  Put "extension=php_imagick.dll" into the php.ini file via Wamp Server.
8)  Restart Wamp Server and hopefully it works.