# Php imagick Error: Class 'Imagick' in php 7

Tags: php

i have this code to count number of pages

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->pingImage('129820.pdf');
echo $image->getNumberImages();
```

i already have `php_imagick.dll` in xampp/php/ext and add `extension=php_imagick.dll` to php.ini

but i still get `Error: Class Imagick not found`

What should i do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find php\_imagick.dll for php 5.5.12 for Windows wampserver 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766737/where-to-find-php-imagick-dll-for-php-5-5-12-for-windows-wampserver-2-5)

Comment: have you checked the php_info if imagic is showing as extension?

Comment: in php_info not showing the imagick

Comment: It means that it is not installed. Follow the instructions posted in the above link and in the end check with phpinfo to see if it was successfully installed. Once you have it the phpinfo will have smthing like following 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/er8hR.png

Comment: Unable to load dynamic library 'path/php_imagick.dll' -1% is not a valid Win32 application , i got this error after installed based on that post

Comment: you have not downloaded the correct version for php 7, read the above link on how to download the correct version of php_imagick.dll.

Comment: i've been download the correct version for php 7